# MongoDB Aggregate Select ALL fields while grouping them by only one specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `Mongoose 6.2.9` and `MongoDB v.4.4.13`

```
I have this schema user_relationships

_id - Object Id
parent_user - Object Id
child_user - Object Id
relationship - String
```

Basically I want to `select * from user_relationships group_by = parent_user`

How can I achieve this by using `aggregatation`?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('user_relationships').aggregate([{
        $group: {
            "_id": "$parent_user",
            "childrens": {
                    $push: "$$ROOT"
             }
        }
}, {
        $project: {
                "parent": "$_id",
                 _id: 0,
                "childrens": 1
        }
}])
```

You can get data using `$group` only this aggregation, I just customized results using $project

Comment: how do I project this by maintaining the the original schema?
where _id is _id and parent_user is parent_user, is this possible?